# Find distinct combination of stations in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with sample data below. Want to know distinct combination of stations present in table.

```
Table Name: train_route

FROM_STN    TO_STN   DISTANCE 
BLR         CHENNAI  800
DEL         MUMBAI   1500
VNS         DEL      1000
MUMBAI      DEL      1497
CHENNAI     BLR      798
```

Distances might be different in different records for same stations. I want to know all the distinct combination of stations present in table.

For ex: For above sample desired output will be

```
FROM_STN    TO_STN
BLR         CHENNAI
DEL         MUMBAI
VNS         DEL
```

The actual table is having billions of records. Anything that can be done using self join?

Comment: Per your posted data there is no duplicates present.

Comment: select distinct from_stn,to_stn from train_route ... oh wait im blind. Do the trains use the same tracks, back and forth ?

Comment: it was a little more legible before the edits !

Comment: Why not Chennai -> Blr

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can help you faster and better – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
select tr.* from
(
select from_stn as frs, to_stn as tos
from train_route
union
select to_stn, from_stn
from train_route) t
join train_route tr on t.frs = tr.from_stn and t.tos = tr.to_stn
```

You can use `union` to remove duplicates.

Comment: what the op is looking for is a combination of `from` and `to`. please read the question again. that i what i understood atleast.

Comment: @vkp This query doesn't give the required output.

Answer (score 0):

If only the distinct combinations and not which station is the to or from is important you can just do a lexical comparison and swap place so that lower station always shows up in the first column and then do a group by:

```
select 
    if(FROM_STN < TO_STN, FROM_STN, TO_STN) station1,
    if(FROM_STN > TO_STN, FROM_STN, TO_STN) station2
from 
    train_route
group by 
    if(FROM_STN < TO_STN, FROM_STN, TO_STN),
    if(FROM_STN > TO_STN, FROM_STN, TO_STN);
```

This would give you a result like:

```
| station1 | station2 |
|----------|----------|
|      BLR |  CHENNAI |
|      DEL |   MUMBAI |
|      DEL |      VNS |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffd36d/3)

Another solution that might perform better (depending on keys and indexes):

```
select distinct from_stn, to_stn
from
(
    select from_stn, to_stn from train_route
    union all
    select to_stn, from_stn from train_route
) all_pairs
where from_stn < to_stn;
```

In the end I don't think there's any way around having to do a lexical comparison.

Comment: This query will give me correct answer. But the actual table is having billions of records. So this query will be very slow in that scenario. Anything that can be done using self join?

Comment: @shruti It should be possible with joins but I can't seem to figure out the query at this time.

Comment: @shruti I added a second solution that might perform better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added my solution using your logic. Please check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.
I have got solution for my question. Just wanted to share with you all.

```
    select a.from_stn,a.to_stn
    from train_route a 
    left join train_route b
    on a.from_stn=b.to_stn and a.to_stn=b.from_stn
    where a.from_stn<=coalesce(b.from_stn,a.from_stn);
```